# Show Image in cmt popup from a byte array

Tags: maui

I have a Product Page and i used ContentPage.Resources to convert the image bytes to an ImageSource as below

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

and

```
  <Image Aspect="Center" 
         WidthRequest="240" 
         HeightRequest="250"
         Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
```

When a user selects a product a popup appears with product information from the selected product which is passed as an object, the only info not appearing is the Image.

```
 private async Task QuantityPopupAsync(Products prod)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await App.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(new QuantityPopupPage(prod));
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Error", "OK");
            }
        }
```

The Products Class Contains the product info to be displayed on the popup

My question is how do i show the images on the popup when the source is a byte array

i have tried to explore if the toolkit referenced popup page has the Resources property as the content page and saw it does not have

Comment: do the XAML snippets you posted apply too `QuantityPopupPage`?

Comment: if the problem is that the popup is a `ContentView` that doesn't support dictionaries, you can place the Resources definitions in the App.xaml so that they are available everywhere in the app

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the **Products** instance pass to the PopupPge correctly. You pass objects when displaying the PopupPage which should have a constructor that accepts a parameter. Since you use data binding for Image, you could pass the **Products** to ViewModel.

So for **QuantityPopupPage.cs**:

```
public partial class QuantityPopupPage : Popup
{
    PopupPageViewModel viewModel;
    public QuantityPopupPage(Products p)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new PopupPageViewModel(p);
    } 
}
```

For **PopupPageViewModel.cs**, such like this:

```
public class PopupPageViewModel
{
    public byte[] ImageByte { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public PopupPageViewModel(Products p)
    {
        ImageByte = p.ImageByte;
        Title = p.Title;
    }
}
```

And you mentioned that cannot find Resources for popup. @Jason gave good suggestion that you could define it in App.xaml then you could reference it anywhere in the app. For more info, you could refer to [Resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-7.0).

For **App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Finally, design the popup xaml as you like

For QuantityPopupPage.xaml,

```
<Image
    x:Name="myImage"
    WidthRequest="240" 
    HeightRequest="250"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    Source="{Binding ImageByte, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi @tipaz, did my answer work for you or is there anything I can help you?  If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer (click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!